# How to avoid port number in django app url in comination with apache2

Tags: python, django, apache2

My django website is hosted on ubuntu apache2 vps which reserves port 80. I want to hide or avoid portnumber in django url. By googling i learnt using port 80 will help for that. But apache2 has reserved port 80.
Is there any workaround to fix it ? Any hint will be greatly apprecitated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Ubuntu, you may try opening this file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And change the listened port from `Listen 80` to something like `Listen 8080`.

However, when you change Apache's port, you need to also change port number in virtual host config. The file will either be at

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf
sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

And change the port from `<VirtualHost: *:80>` to `<VirtualHost: *:8080>`

Lastly, restart the Apache server.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2 #SystemD
sudo service apache2 restart #SysVInit
```

Hope this helps!